# CodeDom Target CPU Architecture

Tags: vb.net, x86, 64-bit, x86-64, codedom

I have currently a problem with Codedom in vb net, because i have some functions that work only with Target CPU set to x86, i wrode them this week on my laptop, thats based on x86, because i was traveling, and i dont have time to re wride them (over 950 lines of Code...)... My Program need to re-compile this code with Codedom, after it makes some small changes, based on the user input, today i copied my project to my main machine (x64) and it turns out, that Codedom compiles everything as Target CPU = AnyCpu, so the compiled application would just work on some machines, that are x86 based...

My question now, becouse i couldnt find anything at google, is there any way to select at Codedom the Target Cpu? Maybe over the CompilerParameters?

thanks

Comment: If some functions are x86-specific, what are you hoping to accomplish by setting the target to x64?

Comment: @Downvoter : He never sets the target to x64, his desktop computer's _operating system_ is x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about using the `CompilerParameters`. Infact you should use  [**`CompilerParameters.CompilerOptions`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.compileroptions(v=vs.110).aspx) which lets you specify additional command line arguments to the compiler.

By specifying the [**`/platform`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/command-line-compiler/platform) argument you'll be able to choose which configuration you want to target:

```
Dim cp As New CompilerParameters
cp.CompilerOptions = "/platform:x86"
```

Comment: @Someone : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!